# FileHelpers not using correct Date format

Tags: .net, f#, filehelpers, f#-scripting

I am attempting to parse records with a `DateTime` field, but FileHelpers is not using the format I am providing. The following is an F# script that should parse the records but throws an error. I believe the problem is related to it being an F# Script because this code works when I use it in a `.fsproj` and run it with `dotnet run`.

```ml
#r "nuget: FileHelpers, 3.5.1"

open System
open FileHelpers

[<DelimitedRecord(","); IgnoreFirst; CLIMutable>]
type RateRecord =
    {
        [<FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")>]
        DateTime : DateTime
        Value : float
    }
  
let sampleData = """DateTime,Value
2020-02-01 00:00,259
2020-02-01 00:01,267
2020-02-01 00:02,270"""

let engine = FileHelperEngine<RateRecord>()
let values = engine.ReadString sampleData
```

The output of running the script. The error message is at the end. Notice that the error message says it attempted to use the `'ddMMyyyy'` format, which is not what I specified.

```
> #r "nuget: FileHelpers, 3.5.1"
-
- open System
- open FileHelpers
-
- [<DelimitedRecord(","); IgnoreFirst; CLIMutable>]
- type RateRecord =
-     {
-         [<FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")>]
-         DateTime : DateTime
-         Value : float
-     }
-
-
- let sampleData = """DateTime,Value
- 2020-02-01 00:00,259
- 2020-02-01 00:01,267
- 2020-02-01 00:02,270"""
-
- let engine = FileHelperEngine<RateRecord>()
- let values = engine.ReadString sampleData
- ;;
[Loading C:\Users\mcrews\AppData\Local\Temp\22000--4251218c-2322-40be-9ae7-fce17ffe54c3\Project.fsproj.fsx]
namespace FSI_0012.Project

FileHelpers.ConvertException: Error Converting '2020-02-01 00:00' to type: 'DateTime'.  There are more chars in the Input String than in the Format string: 'ddMMyyyy'
   at FileHelpers.Converters.DateTimeConverter.StringToField(String from)
   at FileHelpers.FieldBase.AssignFromString(ExtractedInfo fieldString, LineInfo line)
   at FileHelpers.FieldBase.ExtractFieldValue(LineInfo line)
   at FileHelpers.RecordOperations.StringToRecord(Object record, LineInfo line, Object[] values)
   at FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine`1.ReadStreamAsList(TextReader reader, Int32 maxRecords, DataTable dt)
   at FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine`1.ReadStream(TextReader reader, Int32 maxRecords)
   at FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine`1.ReadString(String source, Int32 maxRecords)
   at FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine`1.ReadString(String source)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0013>.$FSI_0013.main@() in d:\Documents\GitHub\Scratchpad\FileHelpers\Test.fsx:line 158
Stopped due to error
>
```

Comment: I just updated the format string. Do they need to be escaped? And yes, I tried without using the attribute and got the same error.

Comment: I tried also specifying the local at "en-US" and there was no change to the output.

Comment: FWIW, when I try your code in an F# project, it seems to work fine, but I get the same error you do in F# interactive. Definitely seems odd. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Not answering your question, but shouldn't your format string be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

Comment: That's why magic is bad: Or, Just 8 Lines of Code: https://www.infoq.com/presentations/8-lines-code-refactoring/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this has something to do with support for .NET Core in F# interactive. Assuming you're using Visual Studio, if you turn off "Use .NET Core Scripting" in Tools > Options, the script works as expected:

[image: Set to False]

Output:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.4.0 for F# 6.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

...

val values: RateRecord[] =
  [|{ DateTime = 2/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
      Value = 259.0 }; { DateTime = 2/1/2020 12:01:00 AM
                         Value = 267.0 }; { DateTime = 2/1/2020 12:02:00 AM
                                            Value = 270.0 }|]
```

The problem is that the `FieldConverter` attribute is ignored when .NET Core scripting is enabled. I'm guessing this is somehow caused by the way that FileHelpers is built and/or issues in .NET Core Scripting, which leads to reflection misbehavior (perhaps subtle incompatibilities in assembly formats between different versions of .NET), but I can't say for sure. Will update if I learn more.

Comment: FWIW, it works for me with VS 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.2.5 even with .Net Core scripting enabled.